# MessagePack-CSharp: Serializing properties with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, msgpack

I am trying to serialize a class with a generic property using the [MessagePack-CSharp](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp) package. Here's a minimum reproducible example of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
using MessagePack;

[MessagePackObject(keyAsPropertyName: true)]
public class Data<T>
{
    T data { get; set; }
    
    public Data(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

Data<int> testData = new(1);
byte[] bytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(testData);
Console.WriteLine(MessagePackSerializer.ConvertToJson(bytes));
```

That program, as written, will throw an exception about not being able to find a matched constructor. If I add a parameterless constructor with an empty body, it no longer throws -- but will return `{}` as the converted JSON, when I really want `{ "data": 1 }`. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being really stupid, I need to specify `public T data { get; set; }`. Alternatively the MessagePack-CSharp README has information about how to tell the serializer to target private fields.